# smb: не работает доступ без пароля

Tags: debian, smb

Есть комп под виндой (10 22H2), в нём сетевая папка, настроен доступ без пароля. Настраивал по гайду отсюда: https://hackware.ru/?p=10923

Есть ноут под дебианом (12.1). Когда пытаюсь подключиться к папке через дельфин, то дельфин требует логин и пароль, с пустыми полями не пускает.

Если в винде создать отдельного пользователя с паролем, дать ему права на папку, а в дельфине вводить его логин и пароль - тогда работает. Но это неудобно, т.к. не весь софт на дебиане умеет ходить в smb с логином и паролем. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать вход без пароля.

Когда подключался с ноута под виндой (7), то всё спокойно работало без пароля, даже притом, что имена пользователей на клиентской и на серверной винде не совпадали. Поэтому думаю, что проблема на стороне дебиана, самба упорно не хочет признавать, что логин-пароль не нужны.

smb1 на стороне винды включено.

Гугл не помогает, всё, что он находит - про случаи, когда линукс выступает сервером, а винда клиентом. У меня-то наоборот.

Comment: Gvfs же . оно умеет с паролем

Comment: Кдешный дельфин тоже умеет с паролем, а толку? Я запускаю из шары видеофайл, а дальше в дело вступает видеопроигрыватель, который тоже должен авторизоваться. Vlc это умеет, а mpv, например, нет. Открывать все видео в vlc я не могу, потому что vlc под линуксом плохо дружит с форматом wmv и криво его перематывает.

Comment: Gvfs-bin стоит?

Comment: KDE стоит, зачем мне что-то гнумовское?

Comment: кеды вроде дружат с gvfs. там делается маунт в /run/user  любой софт ходит как на примонтированный каталог.